# SRS document relation to contract signing in software development ( b2b )

Tags: specifications, requirements, contract, b2b

I was always wondering whats the relation of the SRS document with the official contract signed between two companies ( one supplies a software project the other is the customer ).

Does the SRS document have to be written before the initial contract signing or after ? And does it stand as an official document that two partners in a b2b relation can use as a contract ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about business practices, not programming as defined by the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between SRS and contract is arbitrary and depends on the mode of collaboration that the parties want to establish with the contract. The main modes are:

- waterfall: the contract refers to the fully detailed finished SRS that has to be implemented. Change is costly and complicated.
- agile time & material: no SRS up front, just a few user stories to fill the first iteration
- agile fixed price: mixture of previous two

Answer (score 0):

As @Matthias has said, the relation between SRS document and contract depends on the collaboration mode.

The SRS document have to be written before the contract as the **`functional and non-functional requirements and implementation goals must be clear`** so that the development is done as required by the customer.

The SRS document is **`an official document and can be used for legal settlements`** as the SRS is a deliverable document that will require the client’s sign-off and approval.

Answer (score 0):

Software requirement specification is one among `‘must have’` document, which is equally important for business and the technical team.

SRS act as a foundation document for `technical team` to prepare for any high or low level technical specification including the solution architecture. I am not adding more at technical side since that wasn’t this question.

Now when it comes to business and in particular the agreement, the SRS communicate and act as a safe bridge between two business. This outlines what consumer can expect  from a complete software and what service provider agree to provide.  This means, both parties get their ground to talk and to negotiate.

Ideally,  when we prepare SRS, we include points such as `product scope, business function, area of coverage, future directio`n and list goes on and on. And this document later `‘signed’` by the stakeholders including the product owners and end user. This `agreement gives both parties a structured understanding of their responsibilities`.

Therefore, for me, it is less likely to initiate any project without a draft version of SRS.

Finally, I wanted to touch the software development process. As you know, we have handful of development process, which we follow to simplify our life of software development. Eg: `Waterfall, VModel, RUP, URUP, Agile are some of them.`

Irrespective of any particular process, if it can provide following;

1. a pleasant journey of end to end software development and it’s
   management.
2. has the ability to align and adopt changing business demand.

What happens if customer change their mind ?

Customer shall `change` their mind over the course of development. Such changes are addressed differently in different process.  In case of `waterfall`, any breaking changes or extra requirement must go through a change requirement management process. This will help you to communicate and quantify time and cost. When it comes to `agile`, we have to add/update/prioritize user stories followed by its impact, cost etc.

In one of the accepted answer, it was mentioned as `‘no upfront SRS’` in agile. I prefer it be reworded as `‘no complete SRS upfront’`. This means, it is less likely to have a complete SRS now a days due to nature of business. But this doesn’t means that no SRS.

To conclude, SRS must be your ‘must have’ document when you deal with external customers. Hence it doesn't really matter which process you follow in your organization.